# After disabling TLS1.2 cipher suit TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, session state server is not working

Tags: ssl, iis, tls1.2, session-state-server

```
Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.  If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the server name.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.  If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the server name.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[HttpException (0x80072746): Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.  If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the server name.]
   System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.MakeRequest(StateProtocolVerb verb, String id, StateProtocolExclusive exclusiveAccess, Int32 extraFlags, Int32 timeout, Int32 lockCookie, Byte[] buf, Int32 cb, Int32 networkTimeout, SessionNDMakeRequestResults& results) +1366
   System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.DoGet(HttpContext context, String id, StateProtocolExclusive exclusiveAccess, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags) +261
   System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags) +54
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem() +170
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +1017
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +703
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +158

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4110.0
```

Answer (score 0):

to resolve the issue you could below steps:

- Start–> Services
- Right-click on the ASP.NET State Service and click “start”

you could set the service to automatic so that it will work after a reboot.

use iis crypto extension to enable or disable protocols, ciphers, hashes, and key exchange algorithms. it is easy to use.

https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto